# .mouseup() and .mousedown() not working with .mousemove()

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, my `.mouseup()` event is not being called. Ideally I'd like to console.log when the user activates `mouseup()`.

Would anyone know what is wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/cBh3B/

```
$('.circle').mousedown(function () {
    console.log('mousedone');
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        console.log(e.pageY);
        $('.circle').offset({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        });
    });
});

$('.circle').mouseup(function () {
    console.log('up');
});

var p = $('.square').position();
console.log(p.left);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are moving the circle away from the cursor once the `mousedown` event is triggered. By the time the mouse button is moved up, the cursor is no longer over the circle, which means that the `$('.circle').mouseup` event will not be called.

If you keep the circle under the mouse then the `mouseup` event will be captured. ([See this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cBh3B/2/).)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: If your element is actually a 'circle' then your problem will most likely be the one evoked by @Peter Olson.

I recommend you try using

```
$('.example').on('mouseup', function(){ console.log('mouseup'); });
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/qsE56/

Seems this way your events are being called.

```
$('.circle').on('mousedown',function () {
    console.log('mousedone');
    $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        console.log(e.pageY);
        $('.circle').offset({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        });
    });
});

$('.circle').on('mouseup', function () {
    console.log('up');
});

var p = $('.square').position();
console.log(p.left);
```

You can also check the log, there is a clear 'up' written on it.